# Button Behavior to pop up a window to grab user input and then do something with it within button method NETBEANS 8.0.2

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am trying to build a GUI for a database movie selector program. I am using netbeans(current version 8.0.2) and i have the button down and i would like a window with a text field to open when the button is pressed and then use that input within the button method to produce a result. say, i want to search the database for a movie i can input the name and press ok and it will ouput on a textArea. how can i do this? i have tried to look at the button options and see the Events>inputMethod>inputMethodTextChange, but this doesnt seem right. thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to add an ActionListener to your JButton, and inside of the listener's actionPerformed method display a JOptionPane, specifically a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)`.

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      String selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(myButton, "Enter a move title");
      // do something with the String here
   }
});
```